# Why is "I can say" used in middle of the sentence in the below context?

Tags: present-perfect

> Julie: Sarah told me. A blog.
>
> Eirc: Of what?
>
> Julie: What do you mean "of what"? A blog of Annabelle. Of every
>   thought that passes through her brain. Her stupid, vapid, insipid I
>   could write a blog. I have thoughts.
>
> Eric: And you're a writer, which is more than **I can say** for Annabelle.

I always think **I can say** should be used at the beginning 
of sentences.

For example: **I can say** he is good at sports etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"More than I can say" is a common phrase used to describe some kind of deficiency. Eric thinks that Annabelle is not a writer, certainly not a good writer, so he cannot say that she is. He thinks that Julie is a writer, so he could say it about Julie. So he can say more about Julie than he can about Annabelle. Eric is using this rather long and indirect phrase to emphasize the strength of his opinion.